# Why if $H_5$ acts on $H_{17}$ by conjugation, this means that $5$ should divide $16$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, automorphism-group

I am trying to understand the relation between the action of a group on one another and the order of the groups, here is a statement said to me by my professor:

"if $H_5$ acts on $H_{17}$ by conjugation, this means that $5|16$ which can not happen." where $H_5$ is a group of prime order $5$ and $H_{17}$ is a group of prime order $17.$

I know that $16$ is the order of the group of automorphisms of $H_{17},$ but still, I did not get what my professor said. Could anyone tell me what theorem says what my professor says?

Comment: By assumption, there is a *homomorphism* $\varphi \colon H_5\to\operatorname {Aut}(H_{17})\cong H_{16}$.

Comment: Indeed you just need  $\left|\operatorname {Aut}(H_{17})\right |=16$, as $\operatorname {Aut}(H_{17})\cong H_{16}$ is a more advanced result

Comment: @Devo by what assumption?

Comment: That $H_5$ acts on $H_{17}$ ("If...").

Answer (score 1):

If $H_5$ acts *non-trivially* on $H_{17}$ by automorphisms, then there is a homomorphism from $H_5$ to $H_{17}^×$, the automorphism group of $H_{17}$, whose order is $16$.  Of course,  if the kernel is not $H_5$, then it's trivial.   There's a couple ways to see that then $5\mid16$.  You could use the first isomorphism theorem,  but you might as well just note that the order of the image of any element in $H_5$ has to be $5$.  But it also has to divide $16$, by Lagrange.